.NET 8 Byte[] DataType in DataSet is missing. Is it by purpose?
Edit : Here's the properties of DataSet, DataTable's column properties from .NET 8 project. System.Byte[] is missing.

I store image thumbnail in mySQL in blob while display the thumbnail in my report via dataset bytearray. Is it missing by purpose? If yes what is the alternative?
And here's the properties of DataSet, DataTable's column properties from .NET Framework project. System.Byte[] is there. I have another .NET 8 project that also uses report binded with DataSet, it is also missing.

I checked my previous project, it is there. Or perhaps it is wrong setting?

I'm sorry, what do those two images represent?

@Flydog57 oh it is dataset table column properties. Showing DataType options difference, there is no Byte[].

No one should need to read the comments to understand the question. Edit your question and provide the FULL and CLEAR explanation that you should have in the first place.

@jmcilhinney aye done captain.

@jmcilhinney anw, I googled about dataset byte[] datataype missing and none related. Something is wrong here.

The .NET 8 documentation remarks for DataColumn.DataType explicitly mention byte [] as a supported column type.  How are you generating those images?  You mention that your byte [] arrays contain image thumbnail data, how are you generating that?  Are you using BinaryFormatter?

Was this column generated automatically from the database, or are you trying to add it after the fact?

@dbc It should be, I couldn't find any dataType to load my thumbnail images. I updated the picture, left side is DataSet and the right side is properties of selected columns. And it is missing in two .NET 8 project, while it's there in .NET Framework project. I can assume that it is not that my visual studio is broken.

@jmcilhinney it's manually added via DataSet designer because the report I am working on is static. It is faster that way.

It does appear that you have happened upon a bug so you should probably report that to Microsoft (Help -> Send Feedback - Report a Problem in VS). In the meantime, I have a workaround for you.
I just tried with a SQL Server database and, if the table and column were generated directly from the database, the column data type was set to System.Byte[], as it should be. That type was not in the drop-down list though, as your screenshot shows. That means that it cannot be selected if you have changed the data type or are creating the column manually. It can be done manually in the underlying code though. Close your DataSet designer for a start and then follow the instructions below.
Firstly, in the Solution Explorer, expand the node for your typed DataSet's XSD, then the designer code file, then the DataSet, then the DataTable containing the column and then double-click on the InitClass method. In that method, you'll find the code to create and add the DataColumns to the DataTable. In the line that creates your column, make sure it includes typeof(byte[]). Based on your screenshot, it probably currently includes typeof(object). Don't save those changes yet.
Secondly, in the Solution Explorer, right-click the XSD node and select Open With and then one of the XML editor options. Towards the bottom of the XML file, you will find lines that define your columns something like this:
<xs:element name="Image" msprop:Generator_UserColumnName="Image" msprop:Generator_ColumnPropNameInTable="ImageColumn" msprop:Generator_ColumnPropNameInRow="Image" msprop:Generator_ColumnVarNameInTable="columnImage" type="xs:base64Binary" minOccurs="0" />

Image was the name of my column, so look for the appropriate column name in your case. Note the attribute above that says type="xs:base64Binary". It will specify a different type for your column but you need to change it to xs:base64Binary.
You should now be able to Save All your changes and reopen your DataSet in the designer and see that the type of your column is now System.Byte[]. That's how it worked for me, anyway.

I got an error "Failed to generate code. Column requires a valid DataType". As it is the only object DataType, I changed into typeof(byte[]) and it works. I also changed DSX via XML editor and it seems like it couldn't recongnize "xs:base64Binary". And while I can build successfully, I cannot open DataSet designer, error said "Value does not fall within the expected range".

I created another DataSet, single Table, single Column of byte and I re-update step by step and it works. The previous DataSet is broken I don't know why but I can just remake it. Took very little time. Thank you very much!

@VincentKrisna, I got that same error message the first time I tried too. I only changed the C# file on that occasion. Making the change to the XML file as well seemed to do the trick. If you tried to save between the first and second step or you had the designer open, it's possible that that was to blame for the error. Al's well that ends well though.
